# Delete files in a folder using Perl

Tags: perl, delete-file

I want to delete all files in a folder,  which contain he word TRAR in their filename.. I hav etried the following :

```
CONFIG_DIR=`pwd`
VENDOR=ericsson-msc
RELEASE=v1
BASE_DIR=/appl/virtuo/gways

system ("cd /appl/virtuo/gways/config/ericsson-msc/v1/spool/input_d; rm-rf *TRAR");
```

Comment: Missing space in the rm command? You may also want to try giving full paths to the commands.

Comment: You can also do it in Perl code: chdir DIRHANDLE; unlink glob "*TRAR";

Comment: I have added the space for the rm, but I keep getting this error :   ./hello: line 4: syntax error at line 6: `(' unexpected
I m quite lost as this is my first per script, basically all I want is for the script to delete those files, when it is run, I m not sure if all the config lines are needed or not

Comment: I don't know what you are attempting, but your code is a mix of Shell-code and Perl-code and will not work with either Shell nor Perl.

Comment: I m trying to attempt this for a Linux environment, I m totally new to both and am attempting to take over another programmers work, so I guess I probably would need to use bash, can I cd to the path and then use rm ? and then to run it via cron every hour.....

Answer (score 1):

remove all your config lines ( are they even perl? )

```
CONFIG_DIR=`pwd`
VENDOR=ericsson-msc
RELEASE=v1
BASE_DIR=/appl/virtuo/gways
```

and

```
system ("cd /appl/virtuo/gways/config/ericsson-msc/v1/spool/input_d; rm -rf *TRAR")
```

should work but you should really be using perl code (unlink, etc)

I suspect you are confusing the usage of perl with how you will use awk in bash scripts.

Comment: This is safer, and I suspect the recursive rm is unecessary "system ("cd /appl/virtuo/gways/config/ericsson-msc/v1/spool/input_d && rm -f *TRAR")

Answer (score 0):

As @Steffen Ullrich said, that isn't Perl or Shell.  But I'll try to make it a little more Perlish for you:

First, note that

1. variables in Perl start with a `$`
2. strings need "quotes around them"
3. statements end with a `;`
4. spaces around `=` are ok and make it all easier to read

so

```
$CONFIG_DIR = `pwd`;
$VENDOR = "ericsson-msc";
$RELEASE = "v1";
$BASE_DIR = "/appl/virtuo/gways";
```

Next, see how you can combine these into a single string like this (I'm guessing that's what you want to do)

```
$DIR_FOR_CLEANING = "$BASE_DIR/config/$VENDOR/$RELEASE/spool/input_d";
```

Lastly, you should be really careful whenever using the `-r` command to `rm` along with a wildcard like `*`.  Look up the man page for `rm` and see if `-r` is something you want to do.  I don't think you need it here, unless you have directories named *TRAR that you want to recurse into to remove.  I'll bet you only have files named *TRAR in that input_d directory.

Also, the command the way you wrote it could fail the `cd` if that directory doesn't exist, and would then proceed to recursively remove *TRAR from whatever directory you're running the script from. But you don't need to change directories at all. Try something like this

```
system ("echo rm -f $DIR_FOR_CLEANING/*TRAR");
```

If the echo command lists the files you do in fact want it to remove, then remove the "echo" and the `rm` will start deleting stuff.